# After finding position of a particular string in sheet 1, need to fill corresponding required values in sheet2

Tags: excel, vba

After finding position of a string in sheet1, need to fill corresponding required values in sheet2.
 Eg: 1. we have found position as C7, now fill data of C8 and B8 from sheet1 to sheet2
Eg: 2. If position is C9, fill data from C10 and B10..... untill loop ends till lastrow

Code used for position finding of string TFMODE

```
For x = 2 To lastrow

If Sheets("sheet1").Cells(x, 3) = TFMODE Then
tmp = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(x, 3).Address(0, 0)
```

Comment: please post sample data to easier understanding it. Also your post doesn't contain any question, what is your problem?

Comment: Also what is the destination for the data? is the logic: find in sheet1(C7)-> find corresponding data in sheet2-> copy data from C8 B8 to some cells in sheet2 next to found value same as C7?

Comment: Sheet1 available data and sheet2 required output...we have to find TFMOD and fill sheet 2 as example attached picture http://expirebox.com/download/b145fe7859b814340fae603ec4bcbc8e.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do this. But if not please give some more explanation, maybe some sample data.

```
For x = 2 To lastrow
    If Sheets("sheet1").Cells(x, 3).Value = TFMODE Then
        Sheets("sheet2").Cells(x + 1, 2).Value = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(x + 1, 2).Value ''this offsets by 1 row
        Sheets("sheet2").Cells(x + 1, 3).Value = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(x + 1, 3).Value ''this offsets by 1 row
    End If
Next
```